# Table Caption below the Table

Tags: tables, captions

I am writing a paper and I would like to have the caption of the table below the table instead I have it on top of it.

This is my code:

```
    \documentclass{article}
% The style file
\usepackage{imav}
% Use the postscript times font!
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{epstopdf}

%\numberwithin{algorithm}{chapter}
%\usepackage{algorithmicx}
% the following package is optional:
%\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{savesym}
\usepackage{subfigure}

\savesymbol{iint}
\savesymbol{iiint}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{txfonts}
```

The table is inserted in this way:

```
\begin{table}
\caption{$c_DA,c_LA$ at wind speed of 9.6 m/s and different pitch angles ($\beta=0\degree$ and $\textbf{T}=0$).}
\label{table:draglift1}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|l|l|}
\hline
\textbf{$\text{Pitch Angle } (\alpha)$}&\multicolumn{2}{c|}{$\mathbf{V_w=9.6\,m/s}$}\\
\hline
$-10\degree$&$c_DA=0.0143$&$c_LA=0.0054$\\
\hline
$0\degree$&$c_DA=0.0142$&$c_LA=0.0017$\\
\hline
$10\degree$&$c_DA=0.0119$&$c_LA=-0.0028$\\
\hline
$20\degree$&$c_DA=0.0139$&$c_LA=0.0018$\\
\hline
$30\degree$&$c_DA=0.0119$&$c_LA=0.0033$\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Thanks for your help,
Fab

Comment: just move the caption line after the `\end{tabular}`

Comment: Beware there will probably be a problem with vertical spacing between the caption and the table/following text. In such a case, swap `abovecaptionskip` and `\belowcaptionskip`.

Answer (score 7):

You can put the caption below the table as suggested by  FionaSmith. To take care of the spaces (about which Bernard alerted you above), use `caption` package and issue

```
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{position=bottom}   %% or below
```

You are good to go.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{position=bottom}
% Use the postscript times font!
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[per-mode=symbol]{siunitx}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
  \begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|l|l|}
\hline
\textbf{$\text{Pitch Angle } (\alpha)$}&\multicolumn{2}{c|}{$\mathbf{V_w=9.6\,m/s}$}\\
\hline
$\SI{-10}{\degree}$&$c_DA=0.0143$&$c_LA=0.0054$\\
\hline
$\SI{0}{\degree}$&$c_DA=0.0142$&$c_LA=0.0017$\\
\hline
$\SI{10}{\degree}$&$c_DA=0.0119$&$c_LA=-0.0028$\\
\hline
$\SI{20}{\degree}$&$c_DA=0.0139$&$c_LA=0.0018$\\
\hline
$\SI{30}{\degree}$&$c_DA=0.0119$&$c_LA=0.0033$\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{$c_DA,c_LA$ at wind speed of \SI{9.6}{\meter\per\second} and different pitch angles ($\beta=\SI{0}{\degree}$ and $\mathbf{T}=0$).}
\label{table:draglift1}
\end{table}
Some text
\end{document}
```

[image]

Also, it is better to use `siunitx` to typeset units as I did.

Comment: How do I wrap this Table 1: and description under the columns?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that OP forgot on her/his question ...

Anyway for exercises with considering last note in Harish Kumar answer  below is variation of his answer. In it used horizontal rules from `booktabs` packages and for number formatting is used `S` column type. Beside this I rearrange table that it is now (according to my taste) more aesthetic and easier to read:

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{position=bottom}
% Use the postscript times font!
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[per-mode=symbol]{siunitx}
\usepackage{bm}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[2]
    \begin{table}[htb]
    \centering
\begin{tabular}{S[table-format= 2.0]<{\si{\degree} }
           *{2}{S[table-format=-1.4]}}
    \toprule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Pitch Angle}}  &
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{$\mathbf{V_w=9.6\,m/s}$}    \\
    \cmidrule(lr){2-3}
{$(\alpha)$}            &   {$c_{DA}$}  &   {$c_{LA}$}      \\
    \midrule
        -10             &   0.0143      &   0.0054          \\
          0             &   0.0142      &   0.0017          \\
         10             &   0.0119      &   -0.0028         \\
         20             &   0.0139      &   0.0018          \\
         30             &   0.0119      &   0.0033          \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
    \caption{Coefficients $c_{DA}$ and $c_{LA}$ at wind speed of \SI{9.6}{\meter\per\second} and different pitch angles ($\beta=\SI{0}{\degree}$ and $\mathbf{T}=0$).}
\label{table:draglift1}
    \end{table}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

Other tiny changes are evident from image and above MWE.