# Space between caption and \bottomrule

Tags: spacing, captions

I have more of a cosmetic sort of problem.

Normally the vertical space between the `\bottomrule` and the caption looks like this:

[image]

But with the code I use, some tables look like this:

[image]

I use the following code:

```
\documentclass[
    12pt, % font size
    ngerman, % german umlaute and german hyphenation
    a4paper, % paper format
    oneside, % one-sided pages
]{article}

% Language
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} % languages
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % utf8

% Font and Styling
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % 8-bit font encoding
\usepackage{lmodern} % better font
\usepackage{titlesec} % enabels the styling of titles, sections etc.
\usepackage{titling} % enables the exact styling of the \maketitle command
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{gensymb} % defines special symbols

% Page
\usepackage[a4paper,top=25mm,bottom=25mm,left=35mm,right=25mm]{geometry} % page geometry

% Graphics
\usepackage{graphicx} % graphics (jpeg)
\usepackage{subcaption} % for subfigures
\usepackage{tikz} % draw figures

% Tables
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{array} 
\usepackage{ragged2e}


\newcommand{\ra}[1]{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{#1}}

\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{>{\small}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{Y}[1]{>{\centering\hsize=#1\hsize\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{O}[1]{>{\raggedright\hsize=#1\hsize\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}
    \selectlanguage{ngerman}

    \begin{table}[h!]
        \centering
        \ra{1.2}
        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth} {@{} Y{.2} O{1.8} @{}}
            \toprule
            \bfseries{\#} &
            \bfseries{Massnahme} \\
            \midrule
            1 &
            Budgetplanung aktuell halten damit Probleme frühzeitig erkannt werden \\

            2 &
            Algorithmen auf effektiver Umgebung testen und allfällige Alternativen finden \\

            3 &
            Hardwareseitig Webcameinstellungen prüfen. Softwareseitig lichtunabhängige Ergänzungen finden. Z.B Eckenerkennung \\

            4 &
            Alternative Objekterkennung finden \\

            5 &
            Zusätzlich über Kamerabild Rechtsvortritt prüfen \\

            6 &
            Geschwindigkeit verringern \\

            7 &
            Früh mittels Fahrzeuglänge Kurvenfahrt testen \\

            8 &
            Motor ersetzen \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabularx}
        \caption{Massnahmen}
        \label{tab:Schlussdiskussion - Massnahmen - Massnahmen}
    \end{table}

\end{document}
```

Can anybody give me a hint what could cause this problem?

Comment: Probably the document class or some package or a definition in your preamble or ... We need to see a [minimal working example](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/minexample/index.html)

Comment: Please post a working example, otherwise we're going to spend more time guessing what packages and libraries you loaded to even just see the result.

Comment: What is `\ra`, please learn *not* to use H, and as the others say: post a full minimal example. My guess: caption package with the setting that table captions go on top, this no space above the caption. But that is guess work as we do not have enough detail.

Comment: Unrelated note: You're using `\bfseries` wrong, it is a switch that affects the following text, not a command that takes an argument. Hence it should in general be `{\bfseries bold stuff}`, or you could use `\textbf{bold stuff}`. When in a table cell you don't need the braces for `\bfseries` though, as the cell forms a group I think.

Comment: i added a example

Comment: `\captionsetup[table]{position=below}`

Comment: @daleif Did you get a new crystall ball for christmas? ;-)

Comment: @Johannes_B That should be an answer! :D

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Table Caption below the Table](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/176157/table-caption-below-the-table)

Comment: @Johannes_B Not really: in that question the `caption` package is not loaded. In this case it's the culprit!

Comment: @egreg Oh, you are right. I didn't find a more suitable Q though. Do you have one at hand?

Comment: Please make your code minimal.

Comment: @Johannes_B I simply don't think it's a duplicate

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for adding an MWE.  The important point in your code is line

```
\usepackage{subcaption}
```

That packages loads internally package `caption` (see documentation with `texdoc subcaption` on your terminal/console), so you are able to use the command

```
\captionsetup[table]{position=below}
```

to get a better distance between table and heading.

Please see the following (minimalized and pretty printed) MWE:

```
\documentclass[%
  12pt,    % font size
  ngerman, % german umlaute and german hyphenation
  a4paper, % paper format
% oneside, % one-sided pages
]{article}

% Language
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} % languages
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % utf8

% Font and Styling
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % 8-bit font encoding
\usepackage{lmodern} % better fon

% Page
\usepackage[a4paper,top=25mm,bottom=25mm,left=35mm,right=25mm]{geometry} % page geometry

% Graphics
\usepackage{subcaption} % for subfigures, calls package caption % <=====

% Tables
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{array} 
%\usepackage{ragged2e}

\newcommand{\ra}[1]{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{#1}}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{>{\small}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{Y}[1]{>{\centering\hsize=#1\hsize\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{O}[1]{>{\raggedright\hsize=#1\hsize\arraybackslash}X}


\begin{document}

\captionsetup[table]{position=below}% <=================================

\selectlanguage{ngerman}

\begin{table}
  \centering
  \ra{1.2}
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth} {@{} Y{.2} O{1.8} @{}}
    \toprule
    \textbf{\#} & \textbf{Massnahme} \\
    \midrule
    1 & Budgetplanung aktuell halten damit Probleme frühzeitig erkannt 
        werden \\
    2 & Algorithmen auf effektiver Umgebung testen und allfällige 
        Alternativen finden \\
    3 & Hardwareseitig Webcameinstellungen prüfen. Softwareseitig 
        lichtunabhängige Ergänzungen finden, z.\,B Eckenerkennung \\
    4 & Alternative Objekterkennung finden \\
    5 & Zusätzlich über Kamerabild Rechtsvortritt prüfen \\
    6 & Geschwindigkeit verringern \\
    7 & Früh mittels Fahrzeuglänge Kurvenfahrt testen \\
    8 & Motor ersetzen \\
  \bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}
  \caption{Massnahmen}
  \label{tab:Schlussdiskussion - Massnahmen - Massnahmen}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

with the wished result:

[image]

So at last the given comment of @Johannes_B was right.